# :not pseudo class cancel :hover animation

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I have an element inside a button that I wanted to animate when I hover it and also when I click on the parent element, the button.

For that I used the *:not* and *:active* pseudo-classes to animate the element after the button click like this :

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: wheat;
}

.box:not(:active) .el {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.el {
  width: fit-content;
  font-size: 100px;
  border: solid thin pink;
}

.el:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'><span class='el'></span></div>
```

When I do that, the element only rotate when I click to his parent container and not when I hover the el.

It seems like the first animation canceled the hover animation. I don't know why and how to enable those both animation states. Do you have an explanation ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: when you hover the element is already rotated with that not() selector so nothing will happen plus the selector has a lower specificity

Comment: Invalid HTML. A div cannot be a child of a button

Comment: I find a tricky solution. Adding a div between the box and the element and add the hover on it, which allows the rotation of everything inside it. Thanks anyway for the reply @TemaniAfif

Comment: Incidentally, the current HTML standard does not allow a `div` element as a child for a `button` element; however, `span` is accepted.

Comment: Sure @Éric I fixed this !

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that without js. CSS :active transition will end when user action is finished

Comment: That is why I used :not pseudo-class, to starting animation when button become inactive (just after click).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what you want to accomplish, but when the parent element is clicked the `transition` property won't work as expected in this scenario because transitions are applied only to properties that have changed. Since the `:active` state is only active while the mouse button is pressed, once you release the mouse button, the `:active` state is no longer applied, and thus, the transition doesn't complete.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 35vw;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: wheat;
}

.box:active .el {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.el {
  width: fit-content;
  font-size: 100px;
  border: solid thin pink;
}

.el:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'><span class='el'></span></div>
```

Comment: Sure, but with the :not pseudoclass, I read that I could trigger the animation just after and indeed thé animation works on click with .box:not(active).el but it is the hover one which no longer works as if the :not active prevented the second hover animation  .